# choosing landing page with php

Tags: php, header, navigation, location

when someone arrives at my site i would like the URL to be at 
to index.php?p=home

```
 <?php
  if (file_exists("pages/$p.php")) {
    include("pages/$p.php");
}else{
 header("Location: index.php?p=home");
}
?>
```

I need this to show up in the URL as if they were landing on that page. as of write now it just lands on my index page till you click a link to open.

I tried making this work with the header location but it does not work... Also I used Include and that works but it does not show the path in the url. I need the path to be correct as if they clicked the home link.

Comment: To change the url, use `window.history.replaceState` see [this]( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) for more info

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am trying to make the landing page home.php instead of index.php. WHen I add you statement nothign renders on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are planning to do but this seems to be a bad approach.

Add this to your `index.php`:

```
Old answer    
    /*
    if(!isset($_GET['p'])){
        header("Location: index.php?p=home");
    }
    */
```

## Edited:

Since it seemed like your `header()` function did not work because of probably any output before the function call, changed answer to:

```
$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
if($page=='index.php' && !isset($_GET['p'])){ 
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=index.php?p=home">'; 
} 
$p = (isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'home'); 
if (file_exists("pages/{$p}.php")) { 
include("pages/{$p}.php"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am trying to make the landing page home.php instead of index.php. WHen I add you statement nothign renders on the page.

Comment: @user3298955 What is your homepage? index.php or home.php? Please explain what you need more clearly.

Comment: i have it set up that the index page just includes what ever .php page you pick from the nav. but instead of having the home page as the index page im including my home.php with the other pages. so when the site loads I want index to grab the home.php page so the active link works on my nav bar

Comment: Well have you added the above code with the code that you posted? Or did you replace it? All that the above code does is if the user types `www.yourwebsite.com/index.php` it will navigate to `www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?p=home`

Comment: no when you go to my site it lands on index.php.
Each page is called $p
once you click a link it takes you too index.php?p=PageName
I just want it to end up with index.php?p=home in the url

Comment: So you mean even if the user clicks on a link you want it to show `index.php?p=home` ?

Comment: like this ? <?php
  $p = $_GET['p'];
  if (file_exists("pages/{$p}.php")) {
    include("pages/{$p}.php");
}
if(!isset($_GET['p'])){
    header("Location: index.php?p=home");
}
?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48190/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-user3298955)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $p = $_GET['p'];
  if (file_exists("pages/{$p}.php")) {
    include("pages/{$p}.php");
}else{
 if ($p != "home")
  header("Location: index.php?p=home");
}
?>
```

Note that this code is not secure as any user may use to to access hidden files and directories.